# what does 'twanger' mean

Tags: word-usage

What does 'twanger' mean in the next sentence from the 'Harry Potter: Order of the Phoenix', page 616

> To activate the hex, just say “Plunk your magic twanger, Froggie!”

My understanding is that the sentence means something to this effect:
To activate the curse, just say "Trow down your magic xxxxxx, Froggie!"

But what does the word 'twanger' mean in this context?

Comment: https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0047712/

Comment: As mentioned in the answer to this question: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/324129/what-does-foaming-burbles-mean the sentence is not from Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix, but is actually from  The Unofficial Harry Potter Vocabulary Builder by Sayre Van Young.

Comment: It's not English.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you all for the comments. Especially to the person who posted the IMDB link.

Turns out there was a show that used the phrase:
https://youtu.be/dNXAWx6tW58?t=1232

As you can hear in the video, the Froggie appears with a twanger-sound.

So, in this instance the twanger means this:

> The sharp, quick sound of a vibrating tight string, for example, of a bow or a musical instrument.

Comment: Unable to watch the video now: is your definition an assumption, or is it based on more than correlation?

Comment: That is the definition of a **twang**. Presumably a 'twanger' is something that makes a twanging sound.

Comment: I would strongly advise against saying 'pluck your (or my) twanger' to any English person, since it would quite possibly be misinterpreted.